# Can't set headers after they are sent: Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In reference to the similar question 
[Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/node-js-error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent)

I was getting a similar error and was able to resolve it by adding

```
return res.redirect(.....);
next()
```

Could some one explain how this works? Can't seem to understand why this resolves the issue

Edit:**Adding more the question**

So i have the following route set up

```
router.get('/register', userDetail, auth.authorize({
    failureRedirect: '/login/failure'
}));
```

And under my **userDetail.js**

```
if(req.securityContext.actor.auth_state !== "LOGGEDIN"){
    return res.redirect(unifiedLoginUrl);
    //next();
}
```

The above code results in an error, can'set headers after sent

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense (calling `next()` after returning). The error you were getting happens when you respond to the same request multiple times, but without you providing more context it's impossible to pinpoint the cause.

Comment: You are right @robertklep, it doesnt make sense i have added more the question

Comment: Can you share more of `userDetail`, specifically what happens with the auth_state _is_ equal to `LOGGEDIN`.